# Joining 4 Pandas data frames & setting 2 index columns

Tags: python, pandas, join, concatenation

Forgive me if this question appears to be a duplicate, but I could not find a past question which matches my exact requirements.

I have a dataframe called "df" which has a datetime index and looks like this:

```
            X1  X2  X3  X4
date                
1/1/2000    10  4   1   6
1/2/2000    9   8   7   2
1/3/2000    7   10  5   3
1/4/2000    10  6   2   7
```

From the Dataframe I have produced 3-dataframes of percentage changes in variables after 1, 2 and 3 days:

```
pct_1 = df.pct_change(1)
pct_2 = df.pct_change(2)
pct_3 = df.pct_change(3)
```

The frame "pct_1" looks like this:

```
             X1       X2       X3       X4
date                
1/1/2000     NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
1/2/2000    -0.10     1.00     6.00    -0.67
1/3/2000    -0.22     0.25    -0.29     0.50
1/4/2000     0.43    -0.40    -0.60     1.33
```

The frame "pct_2" looks like this:

```
            X1      X2      X3      X4
date                
1/1/2000    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1/2/2000    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1/3/2000   -0.30    1.50    4.00   -0.50
1/4/2000    0.11   -0.25   -0.71    2.50
```

The frame "pct_3" looks like this:

```
            X1  X2  X3   X4
date                
1/1/2000    NaN NaN NaN NaN
1/2/2000    NaN NaN NaN NaN
1/3/2000    NaN NaN NaN NaN
1/4/2000    0.0 0.5 1.0 0.166667
```

I have another dataframe, called "regions" which looks like this:

```
Region  Priority
X1         1
X2         2
X3         3
X4         1
```

My end goal is to produce something that looks like this:

```
                        pct_1   pct_2   pct_3   priority
date    region              
1/1/2000    X1          NaN     NaN     NaN     1
1/2/2000    X2          1.00    NaN     NaN     2
1/3/2000    X3         -0.29    4.00    NaN     3
1/4/2000    X4          1.33    2.50    0.17    1
```

Does anyone have an idea of how this could be done? I have no clue about the logic or anything. I just know what I want the end product to look like.

Comment: Can you change `{insert number}` by data from `pct_1, pct_2, pct_3`, e.g. only last row? Do you need one column only?

Comment: there is same number of rows in both DataFrames - `df` and `regions`?

Comment: Am editing the final frame with actual values for the question to be clear

Comment: Super, also you can specify logic of apending `regions`, especially if different rows in `df` and `regions` DataFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Computing the data frames `pct_1`, `pct_2`, `pct_3` is straight forward but when joining them, you have to reformat the data. Check out [Pandas-Reshaping](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html?highlight=reshape)

Assuming `Region` column have unique values.

```py
str1 = r'''
date        X1  X2  X3  X4
1/1/2000    10  4   1   6
1/2/2000    9   8   7   2
1/3/2000    7   10  5   3
1/4/2000    10  6   2   7'''

str2=r'''
Region  Priority
X1         1
X2         2
X3         3
X4         1
'''

reg = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(str2), sep='\\s+')

# Read data
df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(str1), sep='\\s+', index_col=0)

# Compute the percent change and stack the Region column
pct = pd.concat([df.pct_change(i) for i in range(1,4)], axis=1, keys=['p1', 'p2', 'p3'])
pct = pct.stack()

pct.index = pct.index.set_names(['date', 'Region'])
pct = pct.reset_index()

# Reformatting
pct = pd.merge(pct, reg, on='Region')
pct = pct.set_index(['date', 'Region'])

print(pct.to_string())
```